# ¿Cómo crear un código auto incrementable en sql developer?

Tags: sql

mi peoblema es que en la sintazis del codigo no me acepta el AUTO INCREMENT para dejarlo como un codigo incrementable segun se creeun nuevo usuario[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: la sintaxis de MYSQL es distinta a la MSSQL, te recomiendo usar [SQL Server Management Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Esto es Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: Etiqueta el motor de base de datos.